# Generics extends and super with ? differencies

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, wildcard

I try to understand generics behaviour in java

I write same code:

common part:

```
class A1{}
class B1 extends A1{}
class C1 extends B1{}
```

case 1:

```
        List<? extends B1> list = new ArrayList<C1>();
        list.add(new A1());// compile error
        list.add(new B1());//compile error
        list.add(new C1());//compile error
```

case 2:

```
        List<? super B1> list = new ArrayList<A1>();
        list.add(new A1());//compile error
        list.add(new B1());//valid
        list.add(new C1());//valid
```

I think that I wrote simmetrical code. Why I see non-simmetrical results?

Comment: Which of those results surprises you and why?

Comment: I thought that super and extends are simmetrical

Comment: Do you understand what they mean? If not, why don't you ask it? And if you do, then what result surprises you?

Comment: @JB Nizet **List<? extends B1> list**  - I cannot add anything via this reference but I can make it when I use **List<? super B1> list**

Comment: After I faced this code I understood that I have wrong generics understanding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`List<? extends B1>` means: a list of an unknow type, which is or extends B1. So it could be a `List<B1>`, a `List<C1>`, or a `List<Foo>` if `Foo` also extends `B1` or `C1`. So you can't add anything to such a list:

```
list.add(new A1); // incorrect, since A1 doesn't even extend B1
list.add(new B1()); // incorrect, since the list could be a List<C1>
list.add(new C1()); // incorrect, since the list could be a List<Foo>
```

The only thing you can add to such a list is null.

`List<? super B1>` means: a list of an unknow type, which is B1 or a superclass or superinterface of `B1`. So it could be a `List<B1>`, a `List<A1>`, or a `List<Object>` (and nothing else). So

```
list.add(new A1()); // incorrect, since the list could be a List<B1>, and A1 is not a B1
list.add(new B1()); // valid, since whatever the type of the list (B1, A1 or Object), B1 is of this type
list.add(new C1()); // valid, since whatever the type of the list (B1, A1 or Object), B1 is of this type
```

If you try to get an element from such a list, though, you can't have any guarantee about its type. The only sure thing is that it's an Object.

The general principle is PECS: Producer Extends, Consumer Super. This means that when a list is a producer (which means you want to get elements from it), then `extends` should be used. When the list is a consumer (which means you want to add elements to it), then `super` should be used.

Comment: It is really helpful answer

Comment: NizetI think it is would good if you meant just <?> in your excellent answer

Comment: So when does someone use `<? extends X>` if you can't add anything to it?

Comment: But now I think about final classes

Comment: JB Nizet What do you think about final classes?

Comment: *So when does someone use <? extends X>*: when you design a method which takes a List as argument and must only read elements from the list. For example: `Collections.binarySearch()`. Final classes are not different from non-final one regarding extends and super.

Comment: **final class B1 extends A1{}** and **List<? extends B1> list = new ArrayList<B1>();**  and  **list.add(new B1());**  -  it doesn't work

Comment: The compiler doesn't care whether the class is final or not. It does the same thing whether the class is final or not. So it still assumes that the list could be a List<Foo> where Foo extends B1 (even if that's not possible given the class is final).